# How to escape forwardslash character in HTML but have it passed correctly to Java web app?

Tags: java, jsp, thymeleaf, html-entities

I have IDs for an entity I'm using in my application that look like this:

```
/6TVYTydu9rBMPuU/zM8Gw==
```

with all sorts of characters. I need to show these entities and link to them through their ID.

```
<a href="/myapp/entity/id_goes_here">Id: ${id_goes_here}</a>
```

This will obviously fail because of the `/`, link will look like `/myapp/entity//6TVYTydu9rBMPuU/zM8Gw==` which is obviously wrong for my application. How can I escape the `/` to the HTML entity `&#47;` and have it passed to the server as a `/` and not as the string `&#47;`?

I'm not using `jsp` for my view rendering (I'm using `thymeleaf`), but if there are any solutions for that, they might help.

Comment: There are no backslashes there... that's a forward slash. And why don't you just make your JSP handle the URL appropriately? I don't think you actually need to escape it.

Comment: Did you tried replacing `/` with `%2f`?

Comment: How does jsp handle URL? You mean with a `<c:url>`? @AgustingMeriles I'm trying that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL encode the ID before setting it in JSP: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

And then URL decode the ID when the server receives it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

E.g

```
URLEncoder.encode(id);
URLEncoder.decode(id);
```